# Gtk gives a warning and won't show my menu item

Tags: python, gtk

The python code: `menu_item = gtk.MenuItem("après")` gives a warning message: `Gtk warning Invalid input string` and the menu item is not shown. What should I add / change to have the menu item displayed?

Comment: @Alex: how do I do that, checking my encoding?

Comment: Try adding `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` in the first line of your script. I forgot encoding errors are returned as SyntaxError so your problem might be something else, but give it a try anyway.

Comment: That was already the first line of the script, and it results in the error / warning message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor is most likely saving the source file in another encoding, such as Latin-1 or Windows-1252, where GTK expects UTF-8. Try replacing `"après"` with `u"apr\u00e8s".encode("utf-8")`. If that makes it work, the problem lies there.

To correctly fix the problem, you need to:

- declare the encoding to Python using the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
- make sure your editor is saving the file in the declared encoding. If necessary, use a hex editor to verify this.
- use Unicode string literals for non-ASCII strings, i.e. `u"après"` instead of `"après"`. Where unicode strings are not accepted, use `u"après".encode("utf-8")`. PyGTK generally accepts Unicode strings, so explicit encoding to UTF-8 should not be necessary.

Comment: Making sure the editor is saving the file as utf-8 solved the problem. Thanks.